# Trait 'Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens' not found in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I will be very appreciative if you could help me solve the problem I got after I try to install Laravel (8) jetstream.

I got this error:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Trait 'Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens' not found
```

What I did before that was to install Laravel to my server:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project

composer require laravel/jetstream

php artisan jetstream:install livewire --teams

npm install

npm run dev

php artisan migrate
```

As I've read in docs (https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/introduction.html).

My User model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasTeams;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhotos;
    use HasTeams;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
```

**UPDATE:**

There is no problem if Laravel have installed by:

laravel new project-name --jet

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install Sanctum as well:

```
composer require laravel/sanctum
```

Comment: Why he does need to install Sanctum as well? What that library does and why it's neccesary?

Comment: @FernandoTorres, that's the "beauty" of frameworks. They cut initial time but there's always a trade off. Sure there is an explanation, but at the end of the day, you're right. Why would one be required to add a component even if it's not used? At lease, not that one is aware of.